# PrependTo fails on a Table of Evaluated funtions

Tags: list-manipulation

My task is something like this:

```
PrependTo[Evaluate[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0.1, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}], {0., 1.}]]
```

where I tried also skipping the

```
Evaluate
```

and I get a

```
PrependTo::rvalue:
```

error.

If I do:

```
a = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0.1, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}];
b = PrependTo[b, {0., 0.}];
```

everything works fine. I want it to be a part of a big code, so doing it in one line without defining the first list separately would speed up the program. And I don't need the first list, only the second one, so why should I store both?

How can I deal with this problem?

Edit: The case is to make

```
Join[{{0., 0.}}, Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0.1, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}], 1]
```

but are there other, maybe better, solutions?

Comment: Please read this answer (and all the nice answers to the question, if possible) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/193

Answer (score 6):

`PrependTo` is probably not what you are seeking for, because it needs a variabl which is assigned. I guess you want `Prepend`

```
Prepend[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0.1, 2 \[Pi], 0.1}], {0., 1.}]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was thinking about.